# Executing function pointer from a in std::vector iterator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write an application that adds function pointers to a vector based on some external event, then iterates through the list. For some reason, I can't seem to get the functions to actually execute despite the fact that they are added to the vector.

What am I missing?

main.cpp

```
#include "GameLogic.h"

GameLogic* gameLogic = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gameLogic = new GameLogic();
    gameLogic->run();
}
```

GameLogic.cpp

```
#include "GameLogic.h"

GameLogic::GameLogic()
{
    FireAction.push_back(&GameLogic::AddCredit);
    FireAction.push_back(&GameLogic::AddPlayer);
}

GameLogic::~GameLogic() {}

void GameLogic::run()
{

    for (std::vector<std::function<void(const GameLogic)>>::iterator it = FireAction.begin(); it != FireAction.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "Iterator Loop" << std::endl;
        (*it);
    }
}

void GameLogic::AddCredit() { std::cout << "Added Credit" << std::endl; }
void GameLogic::AddPlayer() { std::cout << "Added Player" << std::endl; }
```

GameLogic.h

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class GameLogic
{
public:
    GameLogic();
    ~GameLogic();
    void run();

private:
    void AddCredit();
    void AddPlayer();

    std::vector<std::function<void(const GameLogic)>> FireAction;
};
```

Execution Output:

```
Iterator Loop
Iterator Loop
```

Expected Output:

```
Iterator Loop
Added Credit
Iterator Loop
Added Player
```

Comment: [OT]: you have memory leak, and you don't need `new` at all: `GameLogic gameLogic;
    gameLogic.run();` would do the job.

Comment: @Jarod42, good point. I'm pretty new to this. Is the memory leak you're talking about because I'm not calling delete (which would be resolved by using your fix)?

Comment: Yes, delete would fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dereferencing the vector iterators to access the stored `std::function` objects, but you are not actually calling their `operator()` to execute your class methods.  You need to add an extra set of parenthesis for those calls, eg:

```cpp
(*it)(*this);
```

This is made clearer if you store the `std::function`s to a local variable before calling them, eg:

```cpp
std::function<void(const GameLogic)> &func = *it;
// better: auto &func = *it;
func(*this);
```

Now, that being said, your `std::function` objects need to take your `GameLogic` object by pointer or reference, instead of by value, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<std::function<void(const GameLogic&)>> FireAction;
...
(*it)(*this);
// or:
// auto &func = *it;
// func(*this);
```

Or:

```cpp
std::vector<std::function<void(const GameLogic*)>> FireAction;
...
(*it)(this);
// or:
// auto &func = *it;
// func(this);
```

You can avoid this requirement by storing lambdas instead of pointer-to-member's, so you don't have to pass around the `GameLogic` object explicitly:

```cpp
std::vector<std::function<void()>> FireAction;
...
FireAction.push_back([this](){ this->AddCredit(); });
FireAction.push_back([this](){ this->AddPlayer(); });
...
(*it)();
// or:
// auto &func = *it;
// func();
```

Lastly, to simply the code even further, consider using `auto` (as seen above) and range-based for loops, eg:

```cpp
void GameLogic::run()
{
    for (auto it = FireAction.begin(); it != FireAction.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "Iterator Loop" << std::endl;
        (*it)();
        // or:
        // auto &func = *it;
        // func();
    }
}
```

Or:

```cpp
void GameLogic::run()
{
    for (auto &func : FireAction)
    {
        std::cout << "Iterator Loop" << std::endl;
        func();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `(*it)` to call a function pointer, you're mistaken.

You should write: `(*it)(...parameters...)` instead, that will get you closer. The parameter needs to be the `GameLogic` object that you expect those member functions to be called upon.

Note: your `std::function<void(const GameLogic)>` should probably be `std::function<void(const GameLogic &)>` or `std::function<void(GameLogic &)>` unless you like making copies of things.